# Inverter a ordem de uma lista de elementos jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Como inverter a ordem com que o jQuery itera uma array de elementos?

Neste caso o que eu gostaria é de inverter o conteúdo dos items dentro da array.

Por exemplo:

```
<ul>
   <li>Item 1</li>
   <li>Item 2</li>
   <li>Item 3</li>
   <li>Item 4</li>
   <li>Item 5</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Gostaria de sugerir, para fins de facilidade de busca e maior coesão com o que está sendo discutido, que fosse feita a troca do titulo desta pergunta para "Inverter a ordem dos elementos de uma lista usando jQuery".
Claro, é só uma sugestão.

Comment: @FReNeTiC, concordo que pode ser mais claro, obrigado. Fiz um modificação agora para ser mais claro.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Em uma linha:

```js
[].reverse.call($('ul li')).appendTo('ul');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
   <li>Item 1</li>
   <li>Item 2</li>
   <li>Item 3</li>
   <li>Item 4</li>
   <li>Item 5</li>
</ul>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Caa97/

Repare que:

- Os objetos jQuery não possuem método `reverse`, é preciso emprestá-lo de `Array.prototype` (ou de uma array qualquer, como fiz acima).
- Essa solução inverte a ordem dos `<li>` no DOM, e não simplesmente troca seus conteúdos.
- O código acima requer referência ou seletor que aponte para o pai dos `<li>`. O seletor que usei funciona para o HTML da pergunta, mas em casos mais complexos (múltiplas listas na página e/ou listas aninhadas) será necessário passar um seletor mais específico, ou referência ao nó exato do DOM.
- Se quiser um código que inverta várias listas de uma vez, ou listas aninhadas, é preciso usar loops ou `.each`, como na [resposta do Sergio](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/111/#112).

Comment: Certo e conciso :) +1

Answer (score 6):

Mais opções:

#### Opção A:

```
$($("ul > li").get().reverse()).each(function (i) {
    $(this).text( 'Item ' + (++i));
});
```

**Demo [aqui](http://jsfiddle.net/mHcAx/)**

#### Opção B

Usando a combinação jQuery com o método [**reverse**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse) de javascript:

```
$.fn.reverse = [].reverse;
$("ul > li").reverse().each(function (i) {
    $(this).text( 'Item ' + (++i));
});
```

**Demo [aqui](http://jsfiddle.net/mHcAx/1/)**

#### Opção C:

usando a `length` (numero de elementos dentro da array) e ir subraindo o `index` de cada elemento:

```
var nr_of_divs = $("ul > li").length;
$("ul > li").each(function (i) {
    $(this).text( 'Item ' + (nr_of_divs - i));
});
```

**Demo [aqui](http://jsfiddle.net/mHcAx/2/)**

#### Opção D

...relacionada com a anterior, usando o método [**.text()**](http://api.jquery.com/text/) (jQuery) que permite uma função retorno.

```
var nr_of_divs = $("ul > li").length;
$("ul > li").text(function (i) {
    return 'Item ' + (nr_of_divs - i);
});
```

**Demo [aqui](http://jsfiddle.net/mHcAx/3/)**

Answer (score 3):

Pensei em uma outra maneira de implementar isto, tratando como uma especie de pilha. [Exemplo no jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6Am7p/).

## Pilha

Primeiramente eu preciso guardar os elementos em uma variável.

```
var elements = $("li");
```

Desta forma os elementos estão ordenados como `1`, `2`, `3`, `4`, `5`. Minha "pilha" se parece com isto:

```
    5     <- last in (último a entrar)
---------
    4
---------
    3
---------
    2
---------
    1     <- first in (primeiro a entrar)
```

#### Splice

O jQuery não possui um método `pop`, mas é possível copiar o mesmo comportamento utilizando:

```
elements.splice( ultimo_indice, 1);
```

Ou seja, vou obtendo os valores da "pilha", já que `5` foi o último a entrar, ele será o primeiro a sair.

Então eu faço:

```
// enquanto houver elementos na pilha, remove e
var e;
while ((e = elements.splice(elements.length - 1, 1)).length)
{
    // re-adiciona o próprio elemento no seu container
    $("ul").append(e[0]);
}
```

Estou tirando na ordem `5`, `4`, `3`, `2`, `1` e os re-inserindo, mudando assim a ordem dos elementos.

---

#### Pop

É possível implementar o método `pop` para ser utilizado diretamente em um objeto jQuery, para isto basta adicionar o método da seguinte forma:

```
!function($) {
    $.fn.pop = function() { return this.splice(this.length - 1, 1)[0]; }
}(jQuery);
```

E para utilizar neste exemplo:

```
var elements = $("li");

var e;
while ((e = elements.pop()))
{
    $("ul").append(e);
}
```

[Exemplo no jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6Am7p/1/)

---

#### Método direto

E um método mais sem graça, mas que é muito eficiente é percorrer os elementos em ordem reversa os re-adicionando:

```
var elements = $("li");

for (var i = elements.length - 1; i >= 0; --i)
{
    $("ul").append(elements[i]);
}
```

---

#### Performance

E para completar um teste de performance: [Invertendo ordem de elementos jsPerf](http://jsperf.com/inverter-ordem-de-elementos)

```
Nome                                    op/s
--------------------------------------------
ModoSplice                             7,582
ModoPop                                7,340
ModoDireto                             8,357
ModoReverse /* [].reverse.call */     11,679 <--
```

Comment: Eu gosto das abordagens com loops simples. Mas os seus testes não estão rodando sem HTML? Compare com http://jsperf.com/inverter-ordem-de-elementos/4

Comment: Oops! Realmente esqueci de colocar o HTML na hora do teste. Corrigi no mesmo link.

Comment: Ah, então o segredo pra não embolar tudo no jsperf é usar id na lista! Fiz uma bagunça nas revisões 2 e 3 do teste, hehe!